# Send massive emails in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Goodnight

Porblem 1.-

I need to send more than 1000 emails for each event created, and for this I use queue (as Laravel's documentation says), but when sending the emails I have to wait until all the emails are sent to return to the view of control Panel

this is my "store" function in NewsEvents.php controller that sends the emails

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $attributes = request()->validate(News::$rules, News::$messages);

    $news = $this->createEntry(News::class, $attributes);

    //queue for sending emails 
     $this->dispatch(new Nevent($news));


    return redirect_to_resource();
}
```

the "handle" function of job "Nevent.php"

```
 public function handle()
{
    //   
     $users=User::where('tipo_user','user')->get();                  
         foreach($users as $user)
         {
             $user->notify(new EventCreated($this->news));
             echo 'enviado correo';
             Informe::create([
                'event_id' => $this->news->id,
                'total' => '1',
                'tipo' => 'invitacion',
                'dst_id' => $user->id,
                'estado' => 'correcto',
            ]);

         }
}
```

What could be the problem?

problem 2.-

How could I send an email for every minute?
since when sending all emails my server responded with this message:

> Domain mu.edu.fi has exceeded the max emails per hour (100/100 (100%)) allowed.  Message will be reattempted later

Comment: It's better to use schedule command for sending email every minute https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling

Answer (score 1):

If u are using Redis server for managing jobs, Laravel provides a simple 
API for Rate Limiting API's

```
Redis::throttle('your job id')->allow(10)->every(60)->then(function () {
// Job logic...
}, function () {


return $this->release(10);
});
```

Hope this helps.